# Object to ImageIcon

Tags: java, object, imageicon

I have this piece of code:

```
public ImageIcon getNextImage() {
    if (PhotoWalker.hasNext()) {
        return (ImageIcon) PhotoWalker.next();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And `PhotoWalker` is an iterator for an ArrayList. And when I run this I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` .

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Something is modifying the `Collection` that the `Iterator` is backed by.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).